# How to create mock for factory classes?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, factory, mocks

In unit testing I want to create mock object for factory classes e.g.

> $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

but I have following error,

```
generation does not exist.
```

So how to generate factory class in in generation when create unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
$rowFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $rawResult = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $rowFactoryMock
            ->method('create')
            ->will($this->returnValue($rawResult));
```

First, you need to create mock of `RawFactory` class then you need to create mock `Raw` class and last you need to assign `$rawResult` to `$rowFactoryMock`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to generate a factory for tests, just mock it even if the class doesn't exist:

```
// pass class name as plain string
$factoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['create'])
    ->getMock();
// set your object as return value
$factoryMock->method('create')
    ->willReturn($this->createMock(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw::class));
```

Hope this helps.